# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am trying to deploy my application on Tomcat 8 but i get this error `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`

and this is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contxtConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!--Security Filter-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>login.htm</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list> 
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

and this is spring configuration file (dispatcher-servlet.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:security= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.iti.annotation.controller,com.iti.dao"/> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" >
    </bean>

    <!--Security-->
    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="javax.servlet.Filter"/>
    <!--Security Authentication-Manager-->
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="samir" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <security:user name="admin" password="ZXCASDDFAERDFD" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!--securing web requests--> 

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
        <security:form-login login-processing-url="/secure_login"
                                 login-page="/login.htm"
                                 username-parameter="username"
                                 password-parameter="password"
                                 authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=e" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.htm"  access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/addPage.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    </security:http>

    <!--session managment-->
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" />
    </security:session-management>
</beans>
```

Maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <!--it's an implementation to @Validate javax interface-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you should to add this dependencies in your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```